# Как сделать разрыв в блоке цитирования?

Tags: поддержка, форматирование, markdown, редактор

Бывает, что нужно разделить блок цитирования на несколько смысловых частей. Как это правильно сделать в разметке Markdown?

Пока что нашел, что можно поставить невалидный тег и лишний разрыв строки:

```
> some text

<x>
> some more text
```

> some text

> some more text

Но это какой-то костыль. Можно это сделать лучше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться комментариями HTML:

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

<!---->

> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Answer (score 4):

> Бывает, что нужно разделить блок цитирования на несколько смысловых частей. Как это правильно сделать в разметке Markdown?

> Бывает, что нужно разделить блок цитирования на несколько смысловых частей. Как это правильно сделать в разметке Markdown?

```
<blockquote>Бывает, что нужно разделить блок цитирования на несколько смысловых частей.
Как это правильно сделать в разметке Markdown?</blockquote>

<blockquote>Бывает, что нужно разделить блок цитирования на несколько смысловых частей.
Как это правильно сделать в разметке Markdown?</blockquote>
```

Comment: Интересно, что у нас расстояние между блоками получается немного разным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, потому что у тебя есть `p` внутри каждой цитаты, и ещё один между ними. А у меня кроме двух цитат ничего нет. Немного не эквивалентная конструкция.