# Проблема с нумерованным списком вкупе с примером кода в ответах

Tags: дефект, поддержка, markdown, блок-кода, список

Проблема в том, что после нумерованного списка проблематично добавить фрагмент кода.
Видео(gif) прилагаю.

```
Браузер Chrome
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты хочешь добавить блок кода внутрь элемента списка?

Comment: @Grundy, написано же, после.

Comment: А чего вопрос-то удалил?

Comment: @Qwertiy. можешь восстановить

Comment: @Grundy, а вроде ж не дубликат - там код в список, а тут - после списка. Больше на вопрос Ника про цитаты похоже - с ответом про `<!-- -->`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот я еще не уверен что именно про это

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4573/ & https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1622/178988

Comment: @Grundy, переоткрыл. И нашёл пост про цитаты - оказывается, Ник там задавал вопрос, а не отвечал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, то есть надо просто другой дубликат? :)

Comment: Да, я пытался добавить блок кода в элемент списка. В ответе было два варианта решения задачи. В итоге конструктор повёл себя странно, на видео все есть. Вечером увидел, что дубликат, подумал, что решение. Хотел вот с утра почитать. Удалил, чтоб не мусорить (:

Comment: Если есть принципиальная разница, то да, теперь я убежден, что хотел добавить код после списка. Но в любом случае, это не сработало для меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некоторые проблемы форматирования markdown можно решить добавлением блока комментария `<!-- -->`. В данном случае, сразу после списка. Пример (см.исходник сообщения через ссылку [править](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/12469/edit)):

---

1. раз
2. два

```
код
```

Comment: Я конечно не разбираюсь в тонкостях разметки markdown, в документации пишут про доп. таб(4 пробела) + к тому, что уже был, что так же не дает удобного результата, после приходится с каждой строкой делать доп. таб. Ваш вариант удобен, и он работает. Если иначе разметка markdown не позволяет сделать, я приму ответ и буду пользоваться. Но мне кажется это костыль, нет?

Answer (score 3):

Если вместо отступа в 4 пробела использовать новый вариант блока кода через 3 бэктика, то он отобразится нормально:

````
1. Первый
2. Второй

```
код
```
````

---

1. Первый
2. Второй

```
код
```